# New build upload fails when other build of the same version is in Beta already

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

Is it possible to submit to App Store Connect new build of the same app version which has been previously approved by the Apple (but not released to the App Store yet).

For example: I have an app version 2.3.0 in the App Store and version 2.4.0 in Beta & Approved Prod Build by Apple. Is it possible at this stage to upload new/updated version of the 2.4.0 to the TestFlight and eventually to Production? Or, since my new version 2.4.0 is already in Beta I now can only release using 2.4.1?

I've tried uploading 2.4.0 and it complain suggesting to update the version. I wonder is there any other option to keep original 2.4.0 version?

Comment: You can never upload an identical build/version number to something you have already uploaded. You always have to increment.

Comment: Of course if the version goes up you can restart the build at zero. But otherwise just keep increasing the build.

Comment: @matt Im normally able to create new build and upload to TestFlight under same version. But this time, I got an error 'file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version' and I wonder is it because I already but the previous build (of the same version) to Beta? Can I cancel this Beta and upload under same version or I need to bump to next mine version?

Comment: Well I think the error message is very clear.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm if there is a way of overwriting it since 2.4.0 has not been released as yet. But if not possible, that's ok.. will need to release as 2.4.1. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: As per matt's comment above, once particular app version is approved by Apple, even if it's not released to App Store, it can't be overwritten. Version of the app needs to be bumped up and re-submitted to the App Store Connect. Then previously approved version needs to be cancelled prior to submitting new version for Apple review again.